# How to replace the name of an element during assignment of a named element?

Tags: r, naming, assign, radix

If I have a named vector, and I'm trying to assign it into a new vector, but there I want it to have a different name, is there a way to avoid it coming out in the format `newname.oldname`, forcing me to re`name()<-` it manually?

Example:

```
a<-c(foo="baz")
a
#    foo 
#   "baz" 

b<-c(baz=a)
b
#  baz.foo 
#    "baz"
```

I want to make it so `b`'s name is *only* "baz", without the ".foo". Is there a way to achieve that directly?

Comment: You can do `b<-c(baz=unname(a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `unname` or `as.vector`

```
c(baz = unname(a))
# baz 
#"baz"
```

Also with `dplyr::lst`, we can automatically name after `unname`ing

```
dplyr::lst(!!unname(a))
```

Comment: thank you! That's what I've been looking for. I'm been trying to search for something like "rename", but that was obviously the wrong direction.